# Running Maven project in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Is there any way I can run Maven project in Netbeans not in a Maven way? Netbeans do it automatically but I just want to run program normally, as a typical Java project (to save time). I want output to look like this:

```
run:
Hello world!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

instead of this:

```
cd C:\Users\mbrnw_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject1; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_15" "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.3\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\"" "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath pl.mbrnwsk.mavenproject1.App" "-Dexec.executable=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_15\\bin\\java.exe" process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building mavenproject1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[resources:resources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\mbrnw_000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject1\src\main\resources

[compiler:compile]
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[exec:exec]
Hello world!
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.143s
Finished at: Fri May 03 16:27:09 CEST 2013
Final Memory: 6M/107M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by turning on Compile on Save in project properties. However please note that in 7.4 (upcoming version) all execution will already be done by Maven exclusively.